# What's a good in memory rabbitmq alternative for .net

Tags: .net, embed, amqp

I need to have a bunch of nodes talking to each other in a rabbitmq manor, messaging/routing/exchanges.  I'd like a service to be embedded as part of the application.  What are my options for this.

I have found:
http://www.codeproject.com/articles/193611/dotnetmq-a-complete-message-queue-system-for-net
But was wondering if there is anything else

Answer (score 2):

ZeroMQ - http://www.zeromq.org/ - might be a good fit.  On the surface it is much simpler and by no means a traditional full MQ solution but it can be organised into very neat chunks to allow for modular designs.

Comment: There is also now a native .Net implementation for ZeroMQ. https://github.com/zeromq/netmq

Comment: It's been a while since I explored the ZeroMQ world so I hadn't seen that implementation before - thanks.  I noticed that the father of AMQP and ZeroMQ, Martin Sustrik, has now started his new package called nanomsg so that might be worth keeping an eye on in the longer term.

Comment: I've spent 3 days trying to use netmq to do even the slightest things that was was simple in rabbitmq. May settle on a simple queue with wcf pipes